# how to launch a fragment of an activity from another activity?

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I have one activity 'A' which has many buttons on it to call several corresponding fragments of another activity 'B'.

Activity 'B' contains a navigation drawer where i have created fragments for all the items that we have in the navigation drawer.

So, how do i immediately launch suppose 'fragment 1' ( i.e one of the items of the navigation drawer), inside Activity B, when Activity A calls Activity B.

Comment: please share some code -  how do you launch Activity B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an extra to your Intent which defines which Fragment should be loaded.

```
intent.putExtra("fragment","FragA");
```

In your onCreate in Activity B:

```
String fragment = getIntent.getStringExtra("fragment");
// Do something to load correct fragment
```

Comment: intent.putExtra("fragment","FragA"); here, what should be written in place of 'fragment' & is 'FragA'  the name of the fragment that is to be loaded?

Comment: "fragment" is the key of the extra. This is used when retrieving it again. The second value, i.e. FragA is the name of your fragment. That should be set depending on the button.

Comment: Also, String fragment = getIntent.getStringExtra("fragment"); in this statement, in onCreate where exactly do i place this statement?

Comment: Before loading the fragment, after setContentView

Comment: Ok got it! Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, your suggestion worked perfectly!                  Here, is what i wrote on button click in activity 'A': ib2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent i3=new Intent(HomePageActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                i3.putExtra("fragment",1);
                startActivity(i3);
            }
        });

Comment: FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new MainFragment()).commit();

        int intentFragment = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("fragment");

        switch (intentFragment)
        {
            case 1:
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new InventoryFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new CalendarFragment()).commit();
                break;
        }

Comment: I extended your advice by adding a switch case to check this condition for all such fragments. Thanks

Comment: Hi, i also want to pass two parameters to the fragment that i am loading, i do know how to pass extras from one activity to another but plz guide on how to pass arguments from an activity to its fragments. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android